# where can I get a list of or database of countries, cities of each country and state/province?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

where can I get a list of or database of countries, cities of each country and state/province for ajax auto suggetstion?
for free! 
while writing this I was thinking if it's possible via the goole map API ?

Comment: btw how would you get it using Google map API ?

Comment: it wouldn't quite work. It would work for  validating it, but when I thought more I realized it wouldn't suggest countries if you gave it one letter

Answer (score 0):

here is demo search of a weather forecast provider:
http://www.wunderground.com/

their API provides much simpler and more accurate data set regarding city/country lookup:
http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/documentation.html#auto